# Using predictors features and results to create a new one

Tags: svm, libsvm, ensemble-learning

I work with bioinformatics and I'm completely new to machine learning, so I don't know if this idea is viable.

There are several predictors that try to predict the molecular nature of a set of a given genes. They use different ML methods (SVM, logistic regression, random forests etc.) and different sets of features in order to achieve that.

Recently, I had the idea of using the features used by these predictors, as well as their final scores, as features of a new predictor that I would train using a public dataset with known labels.

After running using the predictors on the dataset and obtaining additional metrics that could be used as features, I had a dataset of 72124 observations with 27 features.

The dataset was unbalanced, as one label totals ~75% of the samples. So, I divided the dataset semi-randomly into a testing (20%) and a training/validation (80%) subsets that had the same proportions of the labels (25:75).

I've chosen to use SVM because it seamed adequate to my dataset and libSVM is quite simple to use. The parameters were chosen using the package's tool that does cross-validation with the training data in order to reduce overfitting.

After training the algorithm, I've tested it in the test dataset and obtained great results (accuracy = 0.993, AUC = 0.9992). Now, I'm uneasy because this seems too good to be true. Is my approach correct?

EDIT: Here are some metrics of the classifiers:

```
|               | Accuracy | Sensibility | Specificity | F1 Score | Youden's J |  AUC  |
|---------------|----------|-------------|-------------|----------|------------|-------|
| Classifier 1  |    0,929 |       0,964 |       0,920 |    0,837 |      0,884 | 0,986 |
| Classifier 2  |    0,866 |       0,962 |       0,844 |    0,732 |      0,806 | 0,962 |
| Classifier 3  |    0,749 |       0,986 |       0,693 |    0,599 |      0,679 | 0,959 |
| Classifier 4  |    0,898 |       0,947 |       0,886 |    0,778 |      0,833 | 0,933 |
| Classifier 5  |    0,937 |       0,946 |       0,935 |    0,852 |      0,882 | 0,981 |
| Classifier 6  |    0,608 |       0,867 |       0,547 |    0,457 |      0,415 | 0,889 |
| Classifier 7  |    0,712 |       0,907 |       0,666 |    0,545 |      0,573 | 0,859 |
|               |          |             |             |          |            |       |
| My classifier |    0,993 |       0,984 |       0,995 |    0,981 |      0,978 | 0,999 |
```

Comment: I believe the meta-analysis tag is inappropriate...

Comment: @Joe_74 I agree and have removed it. User apcamargo can restore it if s/he wishes

Comment: First, you should look a the confusion matrices of the predictors, not the raw accuracy. That will give you more info.http://www.dataschool.io/simple-guide-to-confusion-matrix-terminology/

Comment: Also, how accurate were the original predictors? Are you seeing a massive improvement? How many parameters are you tuning in cross validation? Just the SVM, or the others as well?

Comment: Finally, I'm sure you did this, but was the test dataset completely separate from the rest of the process?

Comment: This is a well established method.  Take a look at the Wikipedia page on [Ensemble Learning](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ensemble_learning)

Comment: Sounds like you were testing on the training data.

Comment: The test and training data were separate. During cross-validation, libSVM tunes the gamma and C parameters.

Comment: I've edited the post with the metrics that I've obtained for each classifier.

Comment: Were any of the models you were combining trained on the same data that you used to train the combined model?  If so, the predictions from the component models contain direct information about the response in your training data, so you would have direct and severe data leakage.

Comment: Not exactly the same data, as I used a newer database version than any of then and, on top of that, I only used a subset (80%) of the database for training that differs from their training subset as I've chosen it randomly.